# Unable to deploy smart contract to test rinkeby using remix ide 0.27.0. creation of smart contract pending

Tags: remix, smart-contract-wallets

When deploying smart contract into Rinkeby testnet, I am getting below message. I tried enabling Metamask developer option and updated Metamask extention. I am getting creation of smart contract pending. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rinkeby network is deprecated since October 5th, 2022. And, no more supported.
Explorer returned to read-only and many RPC endpoints stopped to respond.
You should migrate to Goerli or Sepolia.